# Can not edit Wordpress preset CSS-classes in own Theme

Tags: theme-development

Good morning,

I'm making my own (classic) theme for the first time. After I installed the test XML data, I noticed that some things weren't displayed correctly. For example, H1-H6 are assigned the CSS class .has-large-font-size, but they have no effect. I see in ChromeDevTools that the class attributes have been assigned. But they don't appear in the CSS area. Not even as an empty rule. Setting rules in my style.css doesn't have any other result either. I have the same difficulty when trying to format the page title, which I get from get_title(), using the costumizer. Works for all elements (for changing colors, fonts, etc.), except for the page title.

Would someone be so kind as to help me on the trail? Thank you!

Comment: it's a little difficult to follow your question or isolate it, it looks like multiple issues are mentioned and it's not clear which one the question is about. Remember this isn't a discussion forum you need a single specific question for which someone can write an answer for. You can open as many of these as you want for each specific thing though, but you are expected to mark the correct answer once you see it.